# How to finish ExpandedControllerActivity when media stream ends on the receiver side?

Tags: android, chromecast

Description : Suppose I am casting a product and stream ends on the receiver side (Seek bar reached to max ), Do cast API provide any callback for those events ?﻿

Answer (score 0):

First, you can always listen to events related to the changes in playback status by registering a [RemoteMediaClient.Listener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/cast/framework/media/RemoteMediaClient.Listener). As for `ExpandedControllerActivity`, I believe it should already have the logic to close itself when it reaches the end (if you have a queue, "reaching the end" means reaching the end of queue). If it is not behaving as such, feel free to open a ticket on our SDK issue tracker.